# Regular Expression to match markdown headings but not code comments

Tags: typescript, markdown, comments, heading

I would like to process a markdown file with typescript and before doing anything, I would like to check it if it has any headings in it. Here is an example markdown content:

````
# heading 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nulla blandit consequat dui, sit amet maximus massa dictum ut.
Quisque tempus lorem a quam hendrerit hendrerit nec vitae turpis.

## heading 1.1

Pellentesque porta blandit ipsum, et vulputate nisl aliquet nec.
Donec gravida lectus ut mauris molestie, eu semper libero sollicitudin.

```
# some script comment
set var=abc
# another comment
echo var
```

Phasellus ut libero leo.
Nam viverra justo sed arcu accumsan sodales.

# heading 2

Praesent pharetra cursus mi, ac vestibulum eros suscipit in.
Aliquam laoreet at ligula sit amet posuere.
Curabitur pellentesque vehicula sodales.
Nulla turpis urna, sagittis vitae quam ac, vehicula pellentesque velit.
````

To find the headings I'm using this regular expression: `new RegExp('^\s*#', 'm')`

This will match the first occurrence of a line which starts with a hashmark (possibly with starting whitespace) but will also match if the actual hashmark is located in a code snippet (in this case the comment in the script). So the following text should not match:

````
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nulla blandit consequat dui, sit amet maximus massa dictum ut.
Quisque tempus lorem a quam hendrerit hendrerit nec vitae turpis.

Pellentesque porta blandit ipsum, et vulputate nisl aliquet nec.
Donec gravida lectus ut mauris molestie, eu semper libero sollicitudin.

```
# some script comment
set var=abc
# another comment
echo var
```

Phasellus ut libero leo.
Nam viverra justo sed arcu accumsan sodales.

Praesent pharetra cursus mi, ac vestibulum eros suscipit in.
Aliquam laoreet at ligula sit amet posuere.
Curabitur pellentesque vehicula sodales.
Nulla turpis urna, sagittis vitae quam ac, vehicula pellentesque velit.
````

Is there a way to exclude it with regular expression? Or should I try it with different approach?

Comment: "Please note, that I had to write a backslash before the code snippet in the example above to make stackoverflow process the content properly, but in the markdown file it is not there."—You can include `\`\`\`` inside a fenced code block by varying the number of backticks. I used four backticks to define the real, outer code blocks in your question which means you can use three backticks inside it without escaping.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use a proper, third-party Markdown parser instead of relying on regular expressions. Search for "markdown parser your-language-here" and try a few out.

Comment: You could use indented code blocks. Then the regex would simply need to require 0-3 spaces before the opening hash mark. 4 or more would be in a code block. In fact, this is how the reference implementation works as it does not support fenced code blocks.

Comment: Hi Guys! Thanks for the tips! Unfortunatelly I have other tasks to attend to, but I had time to check some markdown parsers. Maybe the regular expression would not work and I may need to process the files anyway to see if there is any headings in it.